# multiple uploads with paramName keys

Tags: dropzone.js

I need to upload multiple files and the server expects a uuid to be present as key.

```
files[cd43fbad-305e-430c-a25c-8f0d7eabbd66]
files[4fa59bc2-c44f-40e0-b793-66a48d6abcb1]
files[56ce2264-6f7e-4824-a0aa-d28631784dda]
```

However with dropzone it seems only the `files` part is changeable. Can somehow hook into the way it appends [] for multiple files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this would be to override the paramName option with a function.

Example:

```
    new Dropzone("#image-dropzone", {
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        parallelUploads: 20,
        maxFiles: 20,
        uploadMultiple: true,
        acceptedFiles: "image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif",
        paramName: function(n) {
            uuid = "do whatever you need to find the uuid";
            return "file[" + uuid + "]";
        },
    });
```

Comment: This is what I ended up using and also works... this.get('dropzone').options.paramName = `file[fileId]`; and did it in the `addedfile` callback but I like your solution better

Comment: would be nice if you could mark it as the correct answer then :)

Comment: Ah thought i did. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem and I solved it.

you can override the js code like below.
add your code in `return` statement.

```
Dropzone.prototype._getParamName = function(n) {
            if (typeof this.options.paramName === "function") {
                return this.options.paramName(n);
            } else {
//                return "" + this.options.paramName + (this.options.uploadMultiple ? "[" + n + "]" : "");
                return "" + this.options.paramName;
            }
        };
```